# I don't know how to interact between classes

Tags: python-2.7

If I have this two classes:

```
class bandido:
    def __init__(self, vida, ataque):
        self.vida = random.randint(40,81)
        self.ataque = random.randint(15,46)
class xiaoling:
    def __init__(self, vida, ataque):
        self.vida = 100
        self.ataque = 100
```

How can I make a fight? and see who wins?

Comment: That's not how OOP works.

Comment: I raged, then laughed. Bravo for trollnes, my friend. =)